# Algoritmo para crear polígonos regulares

Tags: html, algoritmos, canvas, svg, lenguaje-agnóstico

Me gustaría recoger varios algoritmos para **dibujar polígonos regulares**. Pueden ser elementos HTML con forma de polígono, pueden ser elementos SVG, pueden ser imágenes creadas en el canvas de HTML5 o en **cualquier lenguaje de programación**.

---

A continuación voy a explicar una manera de crear polígonos regulares utilizando elementos HTML. Por ejemplo en el caso en el cual quiero crear pentágonos voy a necesitar 5 elementos div girados alrededor del centro unos 360/5 grados hexadecimales.

En el siguiente ejemplo los sectores utilizados para dibujar los polígonos son semitransparentes. Comente la última línea de CSS  (`opacity: .5;`) para ver los polígonos opacos.

```js
// crea una nueve hoja de estilos y la agrega al head
const s = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(s);
// un grado sexagesimal en radianes
const rad = Math.PI / 180;
// el centro del polígono regular
let centro = 70;
let h = 50;// la altura de los rectángulos (div) utilizados para dibujar el polígono regular

// establece la altura y la anchura de la caja que alberga el nuevo polígono
s.textContent = '.gon{height:' + (2 * centro) + 'px; width:' + (2 * centro) + 'px; }';


function algoritmoPoligono(n, padre){
  //número mínimo de lados: 4 
  n = (n > 3) ? n : 4;
  // el angulo de rotación alrededor del centro
  let angulo = 360 / n;
  // calcula el tamaño de los lados del polígono
  let w = 2 * h * Math.tan(.5 * angulo * rad);
  // establece los estilos pde los sectores
  s.textContent += `#${padre} .sector{width:${w}px; 
                                  height:${h}px; 
                                  top:${centro}px; 
                                  left:${centro - w / 2}px;}`;
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // crea los sectores en función del número de lados del polígono
    var sector = document.createElement("div");
    sector.setAttribute("class", "sector");
    document.querySelector(`#${padre}`).appendChild(sector);
    // establece la rotación de cada sector
    s.textContent += `#${padre} .sector:nth-child(${i}){transform:rotate(${i * angulo}deg);}`
  }
}

algoritmoPoligono(5, "penta");
algoritmoPoligono(6, "hexa");
algoritmoPoligono(7, "hepta");
```

```css
.gon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  outline:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.sector {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: currentColor;
  transform-origin: center top;
  /* comente la siguiente línea para ver los polígonos opacos */
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id="penta" class="gon"></div>
<div id="hexa"  class="gon"></div>
<div id="hepta" class="gon"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Usando la formula general para calcular los puntos de cada vértice, en R sería:

```
N <- 6       # Cantidad de lados
n <- 1:N     # Vértices
r <- 1       # radio (tamaño del polígono)
theta <- 0   # Angulo de inclinación
centro <- 0  # Coordenadas del centro

x = r * cos(2*pi*n/N + theta) + centro
y = r * sin(2*pi*n/N + theta) + centro

plot(x, y, type="l")
polygon(x, y, col="blue")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Un polígono regular es un polígono en el que todos los lados tienen la misma longitud y todos los ángulos interiores tienen el mismo valor. Los polígonos regulares se pueden inscribir perfectamente en una circunferencia.

A continuación voy a explicar dos algoritmos para dibujar polígonos regulares. En los dos ejemplos el resultado es un triangulo ya que el número de vertices es 3:

> let puntos = algoritmoPoly(**3**, 100);

#### 1.

Todos los ángulos centrales de un polígono regular son iguales entre si y su valor en radianes puede obtenerse a partir del número de lados del polígono. El primer algoritmo calcula la posición de los vertices de un polígono regular y devuelve un a array de puntos. Ulteriormente este array puede ser utilizado para dibujar el polígono.

```js
function algoritmoPoly(gon,R){
let puntos = []
for(let a = 0; a < 2*Math.PI; a+=2*Math.PI/gon){  
  let x = R*Math.cos(a);
  let y = R*Math.sin(a);
  puntos.push({x,y})
}
// la función devuelve un array de puntos representando los vertices del polígono
return puntos;
}

// un triangulo ya que el número de vertices es 3
let puntos = algoritmoPoly(3, 100);


// dibuja el polígono en canvas
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let cw = c.width = 250;
let ch = c.height= 250;
// translada el contexto en el centro del canvas
ctx.translate(cw/2, ch/2);
// dibuja el polígono
ctx.beginPath();
puntos.forEach(p=>{ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y)});
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{background:#d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

#### 2.

Este otro algoritmo es muy interesante ya que permite dibujar el polígono **utilizando coordenadas polares**

```js
function algoritmoPoly(gon,R){
let puntos = []
for(let a = 0; a < 2*Math.PI; a+=.02){
  // calcula la distáncia entre el centro y un punto situado en el trazado 
  let r = R * Math.cos(Math.PI/gon) /
          Math.cos( a % (2*Math.PI/gon) - Math.PI/gon);
  
  let x = r*Math.cos(a);
  let y = r*Math.sin(a);
  puntos.push({x,y})
}
//devuelve el array de los puntos que describe el polígono regular
return puntos;
}

// un triángulo ya que el número de vertices es 3
let puntos = algoritmoPoly(3, 100)


// dibuja el triangulo en el canvas
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let cw = c.width = 250;
let ch = c.height= 250;


ctx.translate(cw/2, ch/2);
ctx.beginPath();
puntos.forEach(p=>{ctx.lineTo(p.x,p.y)});
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke()
```

```css
canvas{background:#d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Para entender mejor que pasa en este caso, a continuación voy utilizar el mismo código pero esta vez voy a dibujar un pequeño circulo para cada punto del array de los puntos.

```js
function algoritmoPoly(gon,R){
let puntos = []
for(let a = 0; a < 2*Math.PI; a+=.05){
  let r = R * Math.cos(Math.PI/gon) /
          Math.cos( a % (2*Math.PI/gon) - Math.PI/gon);
  
  let x = r*Math.cos(a);
  let y = r*Math.sin(a);
  puntos.push({x,y})
}
return puntos;
}

let puntos = algoritmoPoly(3, 100)



let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let cw = c.width = 400;
let ch = c.height= 400;


ctx.translate(cw/2, ch/2);

//dibuja un pequeño circulo en cada punto del array de los puntos
puntos.forEach(p=>{
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,2,0,2*Math.PI)
ctx.stroke()
});
```

```css
canvas{background:#d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```